# VideoProperties Set Year and Title

Tags: c#, uwp, io, metadata

I know how to retrieve the data `await file.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync ();` and set values to to both Year and Title, however when I attempt to `SavePropertiesAsync ();` my software crashes and returns no error upon closure how do I save the properties to the file?

Comment: When I set values for Year and Title of VideoProperties and then call the SavePropertiesAsync() method to save them, it worked well, the app didn't crash. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? In addition, what type of the file you tried to save properties with it?

Comment: it was an avi file, if it matters it was an empty file.

Comment: If you test another type(e.g. .mov, .mp4, etc.), will the same issue occur?